# How to specify the directory where the migration in MVC6 will be created?

Tags: asp.net, migration, entity-framework-migrations

When I have created the MyContext using Code First, the migration files usually create to ./Migrations. So how to change the other directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when enabling migration u can specify directory like this :

```
enable-migrations -EnableAutomaticMigration:$false -MigrationsDirectory    Migrations\CustomerDatabases -ContextTypeName FullyQualifiedContextName
```